# Copy filtered fields from one sheet to another without activating

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have a workbook with two sheets.
First is called "Forma"
Second is called "Prices"

I go to Forma, with some VBA shapes I choose a product category. I tag this category name in A1 cell of sheet Prices and then filter products according to this category and then copy filtered ones in Forma again.

Because of activating and deactivating sheets the procedure is working but it is blinking screens between activations. Any better way?

That is a part of my code:

```vb
With ActiveSheet
    range("j7: m30").ClearContents
End With

'Tag the category in Prices Table
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prices").Cells(1, 1).Value = "CategoryName.ex.Computers"

'Filtering and selecting products comparing A1 with Column 3 Categories
Worksheets("Prices").Activate

range("A1:K300").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=range("a1").Value

'Copy filtered in Forma Sheet
Dim DbExtract, DuplicateRecords As Worksheet
Set DbExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prices")
Set DuplicateRecords = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Forma")

DbExtract.range("D3:f5000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
DuplicateRecords.Cells(7, 10).PasteSpecial
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Copy Filtered Range

- Not `activating` and not `selecting` will increase performance.
- Turning off `Application.ScreenUpdating` will stop the screen from 'blinking'.
- Using variables will increase readability.
- Something like the following code could put you on the right track.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyCategory()
    
    Const Criteria As String = "CategoryName.ex.Computers"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = wb.Worksheets("Prices")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    If src.AutoFilterMode Then
        src.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    src.Range("A1").Value = Criteria
    src.Range("A1:K300").AutoFilter Field:=3, _
                                    Criteria1:=Criteria
    
    Dim dst As Worksheet
    Set dst = wb.Worksheets("Forma")
    
    dst.Range("J7: M30").ClearContents
    
    src.Range("D3:F300").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy dst.Range("J7")
    ' If you need some special pasting then rather use the following 3 lines.
    'src.Range("D3:F300").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    'dst.Range("J7").PasteSpecial
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub
```